# Как залить изображение через Drupal?

Tags: cms, drupal

Пытался залить изображение через `Drupal`, установил модуль `CKeditor` для того чтобы залить фотографию через свой компьютер, однако данный модуль не имеет той функции чтобы залить фото.

Скажите, есть ли другие пути как например на `WordPress` когда ты грузишь фото в библиотеку и уже оттуда копируешь ссылки `url` для вставки фото?

Answer (score 0):

Плагин Base64 Image для CKeditor позволяет делать загрузку фото, но лично я пользовался IMCE, так же есть elFinder.

[Base64 Image](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/base64image)

[imce](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce)

[elFinder](https://www.drupal.org/project/elfinder)